# Encapsulation and classes

Tags: java, class

For this question, I set certain variables and would like to change them. However when I try to do so, the output comes out as "null, 0, 0". I wonder if I am making a mistake with the getters or the setters. Or am I doing the actual "changing of code" wrong?

```
public class Laptop{
    private String brand;
    private int battery;
    private int  brightness;

public Laptop(String brand, int battery, double brightness){
    brand = "Dell";
    battery = 10;
    brightness = 50;
}

public Laptop(String brand){
    
}

public int getbrightness(){
    return brightness;
}

public int getbattery(){
    return battery;
}

public String getbrand(){
    return brand;
}


public void setBrand(String newbrand){
    brand=newbrand;
}

public void setBattery(int newbattery){
 battery=newbattery;
}

public void setBrightness(int newbrightness){
    brightness=newbrightness;
}


public String toString(){
    String sr= "Brand: " + getbrand() + " Battery percentege: " + getbattery() + " Brightness: " + getbrightness(); 
    return sr;
}

public static void main (String[]args){
    Laptop HP = new Laptop("HP",  0 ,  10);
    System.out.println(HP);
}



}
```

Comment: `brand = "Dell";` in the constructor will assign to the *constructor parameter* named `brand`. Not to the class field called `brand`. To set the latter use `this.brand = "Dell";` (or ideally `this.brand = brand`)

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor, your parameters have the same names as the fields in the class, which means they *shadow* the fields. So your constructor is simply assigning "Dell", 10, and 50 to the parameters rather than assigning values to the fields.

To indicate that you are referring to the field and not the parameter, you can prefix it with the `this` qualifier:

```
public Laptop(String brand, int battery, double brightness){
    this.brand = "Dell";
    this.battery = 10;
    this.brightness = 50;
}
```

You should assign the parameter values to the fields instead of using hard-coded values, though:

```
this.brand = brand;
this.battery = battery;
this.brightness = brightness;
```

Note that had you declared your parameters `final`, the compiler would have caught this error:

```
public Laptop(final String brand, final int battery, final double brightness) {
   brand = "Dell";   // <- won't work!
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is not referring to your class variables. To fix it, use `this` to disambiguate variable names. If you don't want to do that, you could have alternatively just renamed your parameters (although it is best to stick with naming conventions as to not get lost).

Solution 1: (Less Secure)

```
public Laptop(String b1, int b2, double b3){
    brand = b1;
    battery = b2;
    brightness = b3;
}
```

Solution 2: (Highly Recommended)

```
public Laptop(String brand, int battery, double brightness){
    this.brand = brand;
    this.battery = battery;
    this.brightness = brightness;
}
```

Also, you don't want to "hardcode" variable values in the constructor. Pass those values in as parameters, that's why you have them in the first place.